# SocketIO - namespaces and rooms

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have a real-time app that each of my clients can hold multiple rooms, so i thought to prepare namespace per client and then unlimited rooms under each client.

The problem is that i don't want all of the namespaces created where the servers goes up but on-demand when the first user of a client enter to the system, then i'll create the namepsace (by io.of) and the user will join the first (default) room for this company.

What do you think? do you have any idea how to implement it?

Comment: Huh?  It is not clear at all what you are trying to do.

Comment: Why not create an object `{}` to hold all the namespaces when the server goes up. When a user of a new client logs on, check if the namespace exists in the object. If yes, use that namespace, and if not, add a new namespace to the object. When it has namespaces, the object might look like this `{"client1": namespaceForClient1, "client2": ...}`. Clean the list up periodically for clients with no users.

Comment: @poshest, the problem is when the user first connect the namespace need to be already ready for connections, if not, the user connecting to the general namespace of SIO. so the only thing i can do is something like that: if the namespace not exist, create it and reload the user page to connect it. little bit problematic behavior.

Comment: Why not (a) have a general namespace for all clients to connect to (b) when client connects to it, server creates 'company' namespace, if it's not already in the `{}` I mentioned (c) server sends to client the company namespace name to connect to (d) client connects to the company namespace

Comment: In any case, the docs http://socket.io/docs/ say "If you have control over all the messages and events emitted for a particular application, using the default / namespace works. If you want to leverage 3rd-party code, or produce code to share with others, socket.io provides a way of namespacing a socket."  Why do you need to use namespaces to separate communications per company? That would be better done with some server logic that restricts communications to within each company.